# Generating Qt resource file in pre-build event

Tags: python, c++, qt, visual-studio-2012, pre-build-event

I'm using Qt 4.8.4 and Visual Studio 2012.

I have an **app-resources** folder full of pictures (skin, sounds) and in project's pre-build event I generate *.qrc resource file via running my own Python script.

```
Command line: python "../common/skin/default/run.py" "../common/skin/default/"
Description:  Creating resource file (*.qrc)
Use in build: Yes
```

The problem is that .qrc file is re-generating each time I do the project build. But skin and sounds do not change so frequently.

Is there any way I can track that my app-resources folder's content was not modified, so I could skip pre-build step?

Comment: You can handle that in you run.py script somehow.

Comment: Yes, it can work. I'm just wondering if I can monitor file changes in pre-build event using Visual Studio methods/approach.

Comment: I wonder why it's not enough to run it only when you manually change some of the files? There are ways to create custom dependency in qmake but it's not that easy and I doubt it's worth it in this case.

Comment: Predelnik, yes I'm starting to lean towards this idea. The point is that developer can forget to re-launch this script and wonder why some UI graphic parts are missing.. Probably, it's not a big deal.